# use React component in input placeholder

Tags: reactjs, input, placeholder

I am trying to use this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-typing-animation

to animate my search input placeholder text.

when I do this:

```
const placeholder = (
    <Typing>
        <span>This span will get typed.</span>
    </Typing>
);

<input type="text" placeholder={placeholder} />
```

it puts [Object object] as a placeholder.

Comment: why do you place it in a input? you can directly use it

Comment: How? I want my input placeholder to have typing animation

Comment: seems to hard to achieve with this plugin and native placeholder

Comment: Try to put plain HTML to placeholder and see what happens. You can't make a placeholder anything but plain text, regardless of React. Use custom input component.